# SQL Server datetime in query

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

In an event management database I have list of all events with a field `startdate`

What I want to do is not to show events passed by an hour. Only events which have not passed by current date and time.

My date and time is in this format `2011-08-24 17:30:00.000`

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: This workded for me accurately DATEDIFF(hour,fb_event.startdate,getdate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read that as you want data where startdate is before a specific date;

```
select 
   *
from T
  where startdate < dateadd(hour, -1, '2011-08-24 17:30:00.000')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I want to compare it with the current date. "if is not passed by one hour from current date"

Comment: Not sure I follow, you want rows where startdate is before an hour from now? if so `... where startdate < dateadd(hour, -1,getdate())`

Comment: This workded for me accurately
DATEDIFF(hour,fb_event.startdate,getdate()

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
From EventTable
WHERE startdate > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

> [GetDate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) - Returns the current database system timestamp as a
>   datetime value.
>
> [DATEADD(datepart , number , date )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) - Returns a specified date
>   with the specified number interval (signed integer) added to a
>   specified datepart of that date.

Comment: I tried this but did not work. It still fetching back dated records as well

Comment: Just fixed the issue. It should be startdate > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())

Comment: In other words, Just want to find different between the specified date and the current date in hours.

Comment: Do you want the event during the last hour or events in a given date range? I am confusing.

Comment: No in a range. Just all records one hour earliear. Means If an event is passed by one hour it means it is expired

Comment: What you have told is contradict for me. Hopefully in this way you could do what you want. If you cannot please give show some actual data with expected result.

Comment: I want to do
if ( datediff(strartdate -getdate()) = 5)
{
//means it is expired, here 5 means one hour ahead and -5 means later
}